# How to check type of a list element

Tags: list, types, prolog

Is there a way to determine the type of an element within a list in Prolog? I know that variables aren't explicitly typed in Prolog, but I need to check whether an element is a number, a specific character, etc. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: For more complex types than primitives, you can look to the SWI_PROLOG record handling mechanism (http://tinyurl.com/2gy53rr). This will allow you to express compound types with named accessor fields, and will automatically generate all the type checking predicates for you, given a record specification. Very useful!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prolog defines a group of built-in predicates for type testing purposes: `var/1`, `atom/1`, `integer/1`, `float/1`, `atomic/1`, `compound/1`, `nonvar/1`, `number/1`, all of them with quite a self-explanatory meaning if you know the data types of the language. For specific characters, you may exploit unification with that character, after checking that the element is not a free variable (otherwise unification is always successful).

Answer (score 6):

You could try this code:

```
isList([_|_]).
isList([]).
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ... and `isList([a|b])` succeeds, but is not a list.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with the question, but what he meant, i think, was `isList([_|Tail]:-isList(Tail).` instead of the first line

Comment: @Ypgie: your suggestion does not terminate for `isList(X)`

Answer (score 2):

To check if a variable is bound to a list, you can use [`is_list/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1).

Answer (score 0):

to check list you could try:

```
listing(is_list/1, list_functor/1).

is_list(X) :-
    functor(X, F, _),
    list_functor(F).

list_functor('.').
list_functor('[]').
```

Answer (score -1):

number/1

See also http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27F.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/predsummary.html%27%29%29

Comment: Incomplete, doesn't answer "but I need to check whether an element is a number, a specific character, etc".