# How to create a predicate that picks up a specific sort of atoms from a list?

Tags: list, integer, prolog, predicate

The predicate I want to create should pick up a specific sort of atoms from a list,
e.g. integers.

prolog should answer to the following request like this:

```
select_integers([1,g,5,k,8], X). 

X = [1,5,8].
```

This predicate should also be able to select two different sorts of atoms, e.g. integers and letters.

```
select([1,g,5,k,8], X, Y).

X = [1,5,8]

Y = [g,k].
```

Unfortunately, my attempts to create a predicate failed... Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: select_integers([_|_],X) :- X is integer.              select([_|_],X,Y) :- X is integer, Y is atom.

Comment: For an empty list, it should be `select_integers([],[])` since it doens't have any integers

Comment: sorry, this should not have been an empty list. it should have been [H|T]. And X should show  a list with integers, that are in the first list.

Comment: So you looking for two different predicates, `select` (which is the same name as a prolog built-in, btw, so not a good name choice) and `select_integers`?

Comment: yes, exactly. oh, i didn't know this, cound name it also in a different way.

Comment: Are you looking to separate just single letter atoms, or any kind of atoms (e.g., `foo` is an atom in prolog)?

Comment: @mbratch i'd like to seperate any kind of atoms

Comment: @user3058876 As a general rule, you should edit your question when you add your code snippets so you can format them properly.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons Sorry, i'll remember. thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SWI-Prolog, you can achieve this for individual cases using `include/3`:

```
?- include(integer, [1,a,2,z,3,b,b], S).
S = [1, 2, 3].
```

`include/3` calls the predicate `integer/1` on each element of the list and collects in S the elements X for which `call(integer, X)` is true (you could write this predicate yourself using `call/1` and the skeleton of the solution dasblinkenlight supplied).

With this predicate in hand, we can easily write a predicate that lets us call `include/3` on the list multiple times, using different types each time:

```
select_type([], _, []).
select_type([Type|Types], List, [S|Selected]) :-
    include(Type, List, S),
    select_type(Types, List, Selected).
```

This predicate takes a list of types as its first argument and gives a list of lists as its third argument. Each list in the latter contains the elements in `List` of the given type. Can be used thus:

```
?- select_type([integer, atom, var, float, is_list], [2.112,A,3.111,A,B,a,2,3,s,d], X).
X = [[2, 3], [a, s, d], [A, A, B], [2.112, 3.111], []].
```

Of course, this kind of predicate needn't be confined to built-in types, but will work with a list of any predicates which have room for an extra argument. E.g.,

```
?- select_type([plus(2,2)], [1,2,3,4,5,6], X).
X = [[4]].
```

because `call(plus(2,2), 4)` is true.

---

**Edit:**

To answer your question more directly, and in accordance with your clarification in the comments, you can write a predicate like your proposed `select/3` thus:

```
select_int_atom(List, Int, Atom) :-
    include(integer, List, Int),
    include(atom, List, Atom).
```

As you can see, this is equivalent to two consecutive calls to `include/3`. Note as remarked by mbratch, you don't want to use `select` for your predicate, since there is already a `select/3` in the core library.

Comment: thanks a lot! another question: how can I define e.g. an atom with the variable "Y"? with call(atom,Y)?

Comment: @user3058876 Sure! Please ask if you have any other questions. Could you elaborate on your question about defining an atom with the variable "Y"? I don't quite understand. Perhaps an example?

Comment: I want to define every integer with an "X" and every atom with an "Y", so that the program gives e.g. the solution X= 1,5,3,4 and Y=a,bg,d. My problem is that in your answer the different sorts of elements are not separated, but put in the same list. (was it understandable this time?sry)

Comment: I still don't follow, sorry. You can't "define" an integer with X, because X is a variable and can stand for anything. Are you asking about writing a predicate like `select_type(List, Int, Atom)` where `Int` and `Atom` will be, respectively, lists of the elements from List that integers and atoms? I.e., are you asking about writing a predicate that uses argument places instead of a list to collect the lists of different elements?

Comment: @user3058876 see my edit. Let me know if that doesn't answer you question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a single rule that has three clauses:

1. The "base" clause says that picking integers from an empty list produces an empty list.
2. The second clause says that picking integers from a list starting in an integer produces the list with the head element that is equal to the initial element of the source list, and the tail produced by recursive invocation of the same rule
3. The last clause says that picking integers from a list that does *not* start in an integer is the same as picking integers from the tail of that list.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
select_integers([],[]).
select_integers([H|T], [H|R]) :- integer(H), select_integers(T, R).
select_integers([H|T], R) :- \+ integer(H), select_integers(T, R).
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/sUNmhj).

Comment: wow, thank you for the great explanation! I'm trying create now the predicate for my second case and my difficulty is how to define two or three variables. what i mean is that I need not only the variable X for integers, but also e.g. Y for atoms and Z for floats.

Comment: @user3058876 Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866440/335858) for built-in predicates that let you detect other types.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for the link. unfortunately it does not help me a lot.

Comment: @mbratch how can I write "not integer"?

Comment: @user3058876 `\+ integer(H)` means "not integer".

Comment: @mbratch that will help OP with getting everything left in the list, but won't help in selecting out three different kinds of element, as specified.

Comment: @aBathologist yes, I agree.

Comment: @user3058876 Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, when you get an answer to your question, and you have a follow-up question that is significantly different from the original one, you should ask a separate question, rather than trying to get a different answer through commenting.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight to be fair, OP did ask how to separate out two different kinds of elements in the question.